# AutoMapper - Create mapping that combines Customer and Person into CustomerModel

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Class **Customer**

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int DiscountValue { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
}
```

Class **Person**

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Class **CustomerModel**

```cs
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int DiscountValue { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> ReceiptsIds { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create mapping that combines `Customer` and `Person` into `CustomerModel`.

```cs
public class AutomapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutomapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<(Customer, Person), CustomerModel>();
     }
}
```

How can I combine Customer and Person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just map from `Customer` to `CustomerModel` as:

**Solution 1:** Specify the property mapping from source to destination via `.ForMember()`.

```cs
CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Person.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Person.Surname))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Person.BirthDate));
```

---

**Solution 2:** Flattening `Person` model via [`.IncludeMembers()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html#includemembers).

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>()
    .IncludeMembers(src => src.Person);
            
cfg.CreateMap<Person, CustomerModel>();
```

[Demo Solution 1 & 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yta7kE)

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: Nice, was writing the flattening part, anyway thanks for link.